# CKEditor 5 - react content always auto selects

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

Using the ckeditor tutorial I have created a plug-in that renders a React form inside the ckeditor 5.

The issue is that the form elements are not editable, as whenever I click on a form element it loses focus and selects a whole generated component.

I noticed that this is due to trying to drag the whole component. Is it possible to disable this behavior so that I can have editable form elements?

Thanks